# CKEditor Uncaught TypeError on text insert

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ckeditor

Strange things happenes...

I am using inline CKEditor in my project

**html:**

```
<div class="artbody" contenteditable="true" id="artbody"></div>
```

**js:**

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
CKEDITOR.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;

var ckbody = CKEDITOR.inline('artbody', {
customConfig: 'artbodyConfig.js',
on: {
        instanceReady: function(){
        periodicBodyData();
    },
},
});

var periodicBodyData = ( function(){    
    return function() {
        if ( isbodynull !== true ) { // isbodynull - flag declared before 
            updatePublishButtonState(updateToDo()); // some funcs. Nothing interesting
        }
        setTimeout( periodicBodyData, 3000 ); // idle
    };
})();
```

So, when i want to insert something in **empty** #artbody (ctrl+v or shift+insert or by context menu) i geting an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null          ckeditor.js:148
```

and nothing is inserts.

BUT! When i trying insert in second time it works fine. Text inserts, error disappears.

So, if i want to insert something, i must press ctrl+v twise. And firt time it throws error... Or. I must type something and make insertion to **nonempty** field.

This situation only occurs in Chrome (i am using 33.0.1750.146). Even IE8 is OK!

P.S. My artbodyConfig.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list' ] },
    { name: 'styles' },
    { name: 'links' },
    { name: 'insert' },
    { name: 'tools' },
];

config.removeButtons =     'Underline,Subscript,Superscript,SpecialChar,HorizontalRule,Styles,Iframe,Flash';
config.format_tags = 'p;h2;h3;h4;h5';

config.defaultLanguage = 'ru';
config.skin = 'weloveit';
config.extraPlugins = 'nota';
config.language = 'ru';
config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;
config.removePlugins = 'pastefromword,about';

config.disableAutoInline = true;
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is wrong with Chrome?!

Comment: Did you try to remove this line? -> setTimeout( periodicBodyData, 3000 );

Comment: Deleting this line does not help :(

Comment: Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: @SambhavSharma, nope